# Login with Github Authorize Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, github-api, asp.net-core-3.1

So I am developing this site using ASP.NET Core 3.1, and I want to enable a "Login with github" function. I think everything is going fine as the only error I found is that when the user logs in and then the page of authorization appears, enter a redirect loop.

Picture of the loop:

[image]

Picture of Github App Settings:

[image]

AuthController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
        }
    }
}
```

Services Config:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySQL(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GitHub";
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("GitHub", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["GitHub:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/github-oauth");
        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
        options.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:login", "login");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "html_url");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:avatar", "avatar_url");
        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var json = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                context.RunClaimActions(json.RootElement);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

If you need some more information or something just ask
thanks for your help.

Comment: First, ensure your system time is sync'd and up-to-date.  in your devTools on browser, "persist log" run this workflow while capturing/record.  after seeing it redirect a few times, toggle your "throttling" network to "offline" (alternative, you can capture traffic with fiddler).  then, can you add your observations on that to your question.  Additionally, we'll need to know whether `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode` call is throwing an exception and/or whether it is being reached.  Have you set a debug point, then attempted debugging - seen the redirect loop occurring in debug session?

Comment: The `Callback` URL is set to `Auth/Login`. And in the Login controller action you are showing login challenge to the user.. that means after login at Github user is redirected to Login, which again shows the challenge which takes user to GitHub, since user is already logged in GitHub redirects back to Login, and Login shows the challenge which take to Github and so on and on on... that's why it is endless redirections... You need to have different endpoint to handle the callback after login at GitHub...

Comment: but i've to set the `Callback URL` to `Auth/Login` , otherwise github login with doesnt work at all